# MySQL is converting my timestamp values to 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I'm new to PHP and am currently still learning. I'm having issues with my registration form I think. `username`, `password`, `email` all insert into MySQL successfully. `registered` and `last_seen` do not.

I thought I was using `getTimestamp()` wrong, but it echos what I need. However when I try to insert both timestamp fields into MySql, I see `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in those fields instead of what it echoed before the sql query. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is much appreciated.

```
    $date = new DateTime();
    $time = $date->getTimestamp();

    echo '<div class="box_grey">' . $time . '</div>';

    $sql = '    INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, registered, last_seen) 
                VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :registered, :last_seen)';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':registered', $time);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last_seen', $time);
    $stmt->execute();

    print '<div class="box_grey">errorCode() ' . $stmt->errorCode() . '<br /><br />';
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());

    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="box_grey">Registered successfully!</div>';
```

Here's what `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` shows me.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User''s unique ID number',  
    `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
    `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,  
    `registered` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
    `last_seen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: +1 to the question for being the first MySQL question I've seen in days not to use the deprecated MySQL APIs. Could you add the table schema though?

Comment: yes, result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE users;" would be helpful.

Comment: JoachimIsaksson, I try my best to follow the guidelines written in http://www.phptherightway.com/ and http://phpbestpractices.org/

@fsw, sorry about that, I added it to my post.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing invalid dates like `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. Use a `NULL` value instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That occurs pretty often.
You're confusing mysql timestamp which is actually a DATETIME like value with UNIX timestamp, which is number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01.

You need to either change field format or the inserting value.
Also you can find some mysql functions handy - CURDATE() or NOW () for example

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,:username,:password,:email,NOW(),NOW())';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password, $email));
```

But personally I'd avoid mysql timestamps. they can be changed unexpectedly, ruining all your data. I'd use `DATETIME` and set all values manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to convert UNIX timestamps to MySQL date:

```
// $date = new DateTime(); $time = $date->getTimestamp();
// $time = time();
// $time = 1360569298;
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (
username, password, email, registered, last_seen
) VALUES (
:username, :password, :email, FROM_UNIXTIME(:registered), FROM_UNIXTIME(:last_seen)
)';
// ....
$stmt->bindParam(':registered', $time);
$stmt->bindParam(':last_seen', $time);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
set timestamp field default value `current_timestamp` and use the query like below
$sql = '    INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) 
            VALUES (:username, :password, :email)';
```

I think it will help you. Thanks.