# Count total posts each day php

Tags: php

I have a function that counts total posts on the whole website

```
function posts_count(){ 
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from posts"));
return $data['total'];
```

}

how do i make it count how many new post were posted each day?
example, Total new post today: 55

I was thinking as i have a date row in the database when a post is posted, i can do something like

```
function posts_count_today(){   
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from posts WHERE date = '$date_today'"));
    return $data['total'];
}
```

where $date_today is obviously the current day but i am sure there is a better function for that like now() or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using NOW is a good idea. If your date-column also includes a time component, consider using the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT count(*) as total from posts WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
```

This will fetch all posts posted today, regardless of time.

Comment: make sense. now in my database, i have a row called `date` and i am sure im doing it wrong but it is varchar(100) and when the form is submitted, it inserts date("y-M-d l H:i a") into the `date` field, should i change it from varchar to timestamp and it will act the same?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME type for that column. If you always want todays date, set the default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: when i changed it to timestamp, i always get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 inserted into the database and i can't find how to fix that. is it something with the inserts date("y-M-d l H:i a")?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to insert with a specific date format. You format the date when you read it. It seems that you are always inserting the current date, so use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or NOW(), eg: `INSERT INTO posts(`date`) VALUES(NOW())`.

Comment: now() does not work, it gives me an error "A non well formed numeric value encountered in " same if i use current_timestamp. i tried this echo date('y-M-d l H:i a', $date) when i got the error

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a column in your tables that records the date they were created? Here's an example of a table with that:

`create table foo(
  foo_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  recorded TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);`

the `recorded` column should never be filled by your program. Leaving it blank will mean that the record will have a timestamp of when the record was entered.

Then you can select all rows based on the `recorded` column.

```
function posts_count_today(){   
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("
      SELECT count(*) as total 
      FROM posts 
      WHERE recorded > '$date_today'
    ")); //<== $date_today will have to be a format mysql understands. Can't remember off the top of my head but should be google-able.

    return $data['total'];
}
```

Comment: i get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 inserted into the database when i use TIMESTAMP for the type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807746/mysql-is-converting-my-timestamp-values-to-0000-00-00

Check that out and see if that helps

Comment: did not really help, i keep getting the zeros.. i have timestamp as the type and i inset now() and it tells me "undefined now() variable"

Comment: can you please help me out? been trying to do this for a few days!

Comment: Hmm, can you update your question with your current code where you insert into the db? That will give us a better picture of what to work with.

Comment: updated. I simple insert the date format into the date field. If i change the date type in the database to TIMESTAMP, i get the zeros instead of the current time and date

Comment: Ah okay, I we have a couple different things we can do here. You could remove the date column from your insert, and then MySql will put the date in there for you using DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. This will be the time when the record was inserted in your db, in the timezone the db is in. If you really want to compute the date in the above PHP, I would recommend changing the date column from TIMESTAMP to int, and storing a unix timestamp. Then it's easy to sort by, easy to format into whatever date you need using javascript or php, and it's easy to move around.

Comment: okay got it to work! how can i update the timestamp when the post is edited?

Comment: So if you went the route of removing the date column from your insert, then you're going to have to do an update query with the column in a format that is recognized by MySQL. Likely this is what your problem was originally. If you did the Unix timestamp way, then you would just update the date column with a new timestamp. Finally, if you wanted to be really weird you could insert the updated row and delete the old row without messing with the date column at all. (though this is more of a hack than a design)

Comment: I am not sure how to use Unix timestamp.. right now i have the 'date' row of type timestamp. everytime data is inserted into a new row, there is a timestamp generated which i then echo where i need it. but how to update it on post edit i do not know

Comment: So here's where your google - fu will come into play. Search for things like "PHP unix timestamp", "Create MySQL date in PHP", "Insert MySql date with PHP", etc.  if you get stuck this might be another question, but a huge part of development is crafting good google search queries :)

Comment: haha been doing that even before i asked the question here! okay thanks!

Comment: Of course. This issue might be worthy of a new question if your searching hasn't yielded anything. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To get the count and date for posts for EACH DAY in the database posts records try this:

```
SELECT count(DATE(`date`)) as total,
DATE(`date`) as distinctDate
FROM posts
WHERE DATE(date) <= DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql

```
select count(*) as count, date from posts group by date
```

PHP code

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $data[$row['date']] = $row['count'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you see count post in each day, you can use this query:

select count(*),date from posts
group by date

but this query return to multi row.